# Turtle Freezes When Parsing Variables

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Let me preface this by saying that I don't have much experience in Python as a whole, so this is probably just some random human error. Either way, I can't figure it out. This is the prototype for a specific-use calculator I'm programming, and I gave point plotting with turtle a try. Every time I finish giving the inputs, it gives the string output but crashes the turtle window. It freezes and says "This window is not responding." Thing is, I tried opening a new program and it can use variables in a clean program, as well as the "dot" function, so I don't know what the hell is happening. Anyways, here's the code.

```
turtle.screensize(100000,100000)
turtle.speed(0)
repeat = 0
turtle.left(90)
def hAxis():
    repeat = 100
    while repeat >= 0:
        turtle.forward(10)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(2.5)
        turtle.left(180)
        turtle.forward(5)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.forward(2.5)
        turtle.left(90)
        repeat = repeat-1
def retCent():
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0,0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.left(90)
hAxis()
retCent()
hAxis()
retCent()
hAxis()
retCent()
hAxis()
transType = input("Type of transformation: ")
if transType == "translation":
    pX = int(input("x pre-coord: "))
    pY = int(input("y pre-coord: "))
    x = int(input("x coord: "))
    y = int(input("y coord: "))
    transX = x - pX 
    transY = y - pY
    pointX = int(input("Point x preval: "))
    pointY = int(input("Point y preval: "))
    finX = pointX + transX
    finY = pointY + transY
    input("(" + str(finX) + "," + str(finY) + ")")
    print("")
    gotoX = finX * 10
    gotoY = finY * 10
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(gotoX)
    turtle.sety(gotoY)
    turtle.dot(1)
```

mom come pick me up i'm scared

Answer (score 0):

The following rethink works for me, despite not knowing what your programming is trying to do!  A `dot(1)` is awfully hard to see -- good luck!

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def axis():
    screen.tracer(False)

    for _ in range(4):
        for _ in range(100):
            turtle.forward(10)
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(2.5)
            turtle.backward(5)
            turtle.forward(2.5)
            turtle.left(90)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(0, 0)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.pendown()

    screen.tracer(True)

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(100_000, 100_000)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

axis()

turtle.penup()

transType = input("Type of transformation: ")

if transType == "translation":
    pX = int(input("x pre-coord: "))
    pY = int(input("y pre-coord: "))

    x = int(input("x coord: "))
    y = int(input("y coord: "))

    transX, transY = x - pX, y - pY

    pointX = int(input("Point x preval: "))
    pointY = int(input("Point y preval: "))

    finX, finY = pointX + transX, pointY + transY

    print("(" + str(finX) + ", " + str(finY) + ")")

    turtle.goto(finX * 10, finY * 10)
    turtle.dot(1)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The purpose of this code is to reduce my math class workload. My class is currently learning transformations and I wanted to make it easier on myself. Ergo, I coded a bunch of really basic calculators. I'm now combining them all into one (this) program and trying to make the turtle plot the points.